# Does my program continue after calling 'parsePacket()' or does it wait till it receives data?

Tags: c++, arduino, udp, esp8266

So, I'm currently not at home, thus I can't try it by myself. I'm having an ESP8266 microcontroller and can talk to it via UDP. Everything works fine, but I was wondering if my code (below) actually waits for a client to send data or if it keeps checking. In other words: Is the 'loop()' function called all the time, or once and then waits at 'Udp.parsePacket()' for a client to send data?

Sorry for asking this, since this can be figured out really quick, but I won't have the chance to do so for some time, but I still want to continue writing my code. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

WiFiUDP Udp

void setup() {
    ...
}

void loop() {

    int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();

    if (packetSize) {
        Serial.printf("Received %d bytes from %s, port %d\n",
        packetSize, Udp.remoteIP().toString().c_str(), Udp.remotePort());
        int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, 255);

        if (len > 0)
      {
          incomingPacket[len] = 0;
      }

      Serial.printf("UDP packet contents: %s\n", incomingPacket);
      if (strcmp(incomingPacket, "LED") == 0) {
          Serial.printf("Turning LED on.");
          digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
          delay(1000);
          Serial.printf("Turning LED off.");
          digitalWrite(0, LOW);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: From https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiUDPParsePacket, it seems not blocking.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetUDPParsePacket) gives no indication that this call is blocking, and in fact has an unconditional `delay(10)` to stop the loop spinning when there is no packet to parse.

I think we can take this to mean that the call is non-blocking, and you should consider having such a delay too.

Comment: @gv99: Yes, probably :P

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiUDPParsePacket) it says that it returns 0 if no package is available, so it is non-blocking. Otherwise it would always return some positive number.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Even blocking functions can famously return spuriously having not found a result. e.g. `select` on a blocking socket can return but give you nothing "activated" in the FD sets. Generally you need to account for that circumstance too. So, the return value isn't really sufficient information to reach the conclusion that the call is non-blocking (though I believe that it is anyway).